# find if matrices intersect for culling test?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am developing a 2d game where I cant rotate my view using the rotation sensor and view different textures on screen.

I am scattering all the textures using this method :

```
public void position(ShaderProgram program, float[] rotationMatrix , float[] projectionMatrix , float longitude , float latitude , float radius)
{
    this.radius = radius;
    viewMat = new float[MATRIX_SIZE];
    mvpMatrix = new float[MATRIX_SIZE];

    // correct coordinate system to fit landscape orientation
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, viewMat);

    //correct the axis so that the direction of Y axis is to the sky and Z is to the front
    Matrix.rotateM(viewMat, 0, -90f, 1f, 0f, 0f);

    // first rotation - longitude
    Matrix.rotateM(viewMat, 0, longitude, 0f, 1f, 0f);

    //second rotation - latitude
    Matrix.rotateM(viewMat, 0, latitude, 1f, 0f, 0f);

    // used to control the distance of viewing the texture (currently only z translation is used)
    Matrix.translateM(viewMat, 0 , 0f , 0f , radius);

    //multiply the adjusted view matrix with projection matrix
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMat, 0);

    //send mvp matrix to shader
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(program.getMatrixLocation(), 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
}
```

however when I render large amount of textures , the framerate becomes very laggy . so I thought about using culling.

how should I perform the culling test after I have a different view matrix for every texture?

what I mean is , how do I compare if the matrix that represent where I'm viewing right now intersects with the matrix represents each texture so I'll decide if to draw it or not ?

Comment: your objects must have a uniform view matrix for the depth to be consistent on your entire scene. then you can enable depth test and the GPU will decide what will be discarded or not. i'm not sure with culling though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways on doing this but each of them will need more then just a matrix. A matrix (assuming the center of the object is at 0,0 without applying any matrix) alone will not handle cases where you may see only a part of the object.

You may define boundaries of the original object with 8 points such as a cube. Imagine if you draw these 8 points with the same matrix as the object the points will appear around the object so that they can define a surface which will box the object itself.

So these points may then be multiplied with your resulting matrix (the whole MVP matrix) which will project them to the openGL drawable part of the coordinate system. Now you only need to check that if any of these points is inside [-1,1] in every axis then you must draw the object. So x, y and z must be between -1 and 1.

Update:

Actually that will not be enough as the intersection may happen even if all of the 8 points are outside those coordinates. You will need a proper algorithm to find the intersection of the 2 shapes...

Comment: do I need a cube even if it's just 2d textures? can I use a rectangle ? and if so , do I do the intersection tests at the shaders or at the java code?

Comment: You can use a rectangle of 4 points. In the shaders those are already done for you. The fragments will not be created for items out of bounds so you have nothing to do there. Also if you are using orthographical projection you may just compare the x and y with the rect in [-1,1] which is much easier. So yes, you do that on the CPU so the GPU has less work.

Comment: if it's already done for me how come the more textures I "draw" (out of bounds) the slower the rendering gets?

Comment: The vertex part is still done. It will still try to compute what part of the polygon needs to be drawn so that whole pipeline gets executed. But the pixels that are out of bounds will be discarded and a fragment shader will not be called for them. You however can not control in the vertex shader to discard some parts of the polygon so it would only make sense to discard the pixel in the fragment shader but as I am saying it does not get to the fragment shader anyway.